# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message 'couldn't connect to host

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Hola e gustaría pedir ayuda por favor, a raíz de un error con la aplicación de MERCADO PAGO.

Tengo un cliente sylviegeronimi.com alojado en un servidor dedicado. El cual tiene  una aplicación WORDPRESS + WOOCOMMERCE /// con el modulo de MERCADOPAGO

Preciso ayuda para comprender el motivo de este error y si se puede corregirlo.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message
>   'couldn't connect to host

/// Corrí un debug y me detalla el siguiente origen:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message
> 'couldn't connect to host' in
> /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php:849
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php(879):
> MPRestClient::exec(Array, '2.1.7')
> #1 /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago-module.php(119):
> MPRestClient::get(Array, '2.1.7')
> #2 /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/mercadopago-gateway.php(212):
> WC_WooMercadoPago_Module::get_categories()
> #3 /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/mercadopago-gateway.php(86):
> WC_WooMercadoPago_Gateway->init_form_fields()
> #4 /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php(105):
> WC_WooMercadoPago_Gateway->__construct()
> #5 /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/incl in /home/ee000669/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php
> on line 849
```

Dejo a continuación un detalle del estado del sistema:

#### WordPress Environment

Site URL: sylviegeronimi.com
WC Version: 2.6.13
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 4.7.2
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 256 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: –
Language: es_ES

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141
PHP Version: 5.6.29
PHP Post Max Size: 32 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.19.7
NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.6.35
Max Upload Size: 32 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Publicación remota: ✔
Obtención remota: ✔

#### Database

WC Database Version: 2.6.13
:
woocommerce_sessions: ✔
woocommerce_api_keys: ✔
woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: ✔
woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: ✔
woocommerce_order_items: ✔
woocommerce_order_itemmeta: ✔
woocommerce_tax_rates: ✔
woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: ✔
woocommerce_shipping_zones: ✔
woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: ✔
woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: ✔
woocommerce_payment_tokens: ✔
woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: ✔

#### Active Plugins (16)

BE Page Builder: por Brandexponents – 4.6.1
BE Portfolio Post: por Brandexponents – 1.1
BE one click import: por BrandExponents – 3.0
ITRO Popup Plugin: por ITRO Team – 5.0.1
Master Slider Pro: por averta – 2.29.0
Meta Box Conditional Logic: por Tan Nguyen – 1.0.8
Meta Box Show Hide: por Rilwis – 0.2.1
Meta Box Tabs: por Rilwis – 0.1.5
Oshine Modules: por Brand Exponents – 1.0.2
Tatsu: por Brand Exponents – 1.0.2
TimThumb Vulnerability Scanner: por Peter Butler – 1.54
Woo Mercado Pago Module: por Mercado Pago – 2.1.7
WooCommerce ARS Currency: por claudiosanches – 2.0
WooCommerce Zoomifier - The Ultimate Responsive WooCommerce Magnifier: por The WP Instinct Team – 1.6
WooCommerce: por WooThemes – 2.6.13
Importador de WordPress: por wordpresspuntoorg – 0.6.3

#### Settings

Force SSL: –
Currency: ARS ($)
Currency Position: left_space
Thousand Separator: .
Decimal Separator: ,
Number of Decimals: 0

#### API

API Enabled: ✔

#### WC Pages

Base de la tienda: #3442 - /creaciones/
Carrito: #14 - /carro/
Finalizar compra: #15 - /finalizar-comprar/
Mi cuenta: #16 - /mi-cuenta/

#### Taxonomies

Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

#### Theme

Name: Oshin
Version: 5.0.1
Author URL: brandexponents.com/
Child Theme: ❌ – Si estás modificando WooCommerce en un tema padre que no has creado personalmente
te recomendamos utilizar un tema hijo. Ver: : Cómo crear un tema hijo

WooCommerce Support: ✔

#### Templates

Overrides: –
`

--

Saludos

Comment: Comprueba que las credenciales sean correctas, el mensaje es: `couldn't connect to host`. ¿antes funcionaba la comunicación con MercadoPago?

Comment: Hola! gracias Mauricio. Si sí... las credenciales son correctas, lamentablemente tuve que desconectar el plugin, ya que probocaba la caída del sitio. Gracias!